# On $NP$, $\oplus P$ and $PP$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

We know $\oplus P^{\oplus P}=\oplus P$, $PP^{\oplus P}\subseteq P^{PP}$ and $NP\subseteq PP$.

1. Is $\oplus P^{PP}=PP$?
2. Why is it difficult to show $NP^{NP}\subseteq PP$?
3. What is the smallest known class $\mathcal C$ such that $PP\subseteq \oplus P^\mathcal C$ holds? Is there any class smaller than $PP$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Unknown. There is an oracle $A$ s.t. $\bigoplus\mathsf{P}^A \not\subseteq \mathsf{PP}^A$.
2. There is an oracle $A$ s.t. $\mathsf{NP}^{\mathsf{NP}^A} \not\subseteq \mathsf{PP}^A$.
3. As far as I know no smaller class than $\mathsf{PP}$ is known to satisfy the inclusion.

Comment: I meant smallest known class.

Answer (score 5):

Concerning 3, I believe $\mathrm{PP\subseteq\oplus P^{C_=P}}$, as there are at least $a$ numbers $x<2^n$ satisfying $P(x)$ if and only if the number of $y<2^n$ such that $P(y)\land|\{x\le y:P(x)\}|=a$ is odd. (Note that there is always at most one such $y$. That is, the argument actually shows $\mathrm{PP\subseteq UP^{C_=P}}$. (In fact, it even shows $\mathrm{UP^{PP}=UP^{C_=P}=UP^{C_=P[1]}}$.))

Comment: You are right, of course.

Comment: @EmilJerabek Just an unrelated query. Can $(Mod_aP)^{Mod_bP}$ be contained in $Mod_aP$ or ${Mod_bP}$ where $a,b$ are coprime?

Comment: That’s highly unlikely.

Comment: And there are oracles relative to which they are not.

Comment: What is the smallest class with $(Mod_aP)^{Mod_bP}$?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek actually I tried parsing your answer. I feel I miss something. How do you use $C_=P$ here and why is there only one such $y$? It will help me a bit more.

Comment: $y$, if it exists, is the $a$th number satisfying $P$. This defines it uniquely. The predicate $|\{x\le y:P(x)\}|=a$ is in $C_=P$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek $|\{x\leq y:P(x)\}|=a$ is in $C_=P$ is a middle point argument. There is at most one such $y$ because $a$ is fixed (So we either have $1$ or $0$). We fix $a=\mbox{half number of paths}$ and query once. Correct? The querying part with $PromiseUP$ is not clear to me. Do we non-deterministically guess something and make the query?

Comment: Also is $PromiseUP^X\subseteq\oplus P^X$ for any oracle?

Comment: I don’t know why I wrote promiseUP, it’s just plain $\mathrm{UP^{C_=P}}$. It’s still the same argument: we guess $y$ and verify it using the $\mathrm{C_=P}$ oracle.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Is there any consequence if $P^{GapP+}$ is in $\oplus P^{C_{=}P}$ or $P^{C_=P}$?

Comment: I don’t know what $\mathrm{P^{GapP+}}$ is. But $\mathrm{P^{GapP}=P^{PP}}$, while $\mathrm{\oplus P^{\oplus P^\mathit X}=\oplus P}^X$, thus it holds that $\mathrm{P^{GapP}\subseteq\oplus P^{GapP}\subseteq\oplus P^{C_=P}}$.